# How to open application info screen via intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Hello everyone how can i use intent to open application information ?
l search in stack overflow and i does not found any thing.

Open screen please.

[**screen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf9q7.png)
[image]

Comment: Before downvote to question, lets help user where he is lacking to ask the question, Let him know that what is wrong and right to ask the question here

Comment: Welcome on SO, There are some rules & regulation here to ask question like you need to show that what have you tried before, Whats problem are you getting in code.. Which questions and answers you are refering...Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.... Then after edit you question then you will  get proper attention ..Here all we are to help you but first you need to ask the proper question..Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to use implicit intent to open application info screen.
In below code I am using `getPackageName()` to get application package.

Try This Code Snippet -

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
 startActivity(intent);
```

This is working for me in Android 9.